# How to take care of duplicates while copying files to a folder in python

Tags: python

I am writing a script in python to consolidate images in different folders to a single folder. There is a possibility of multiple image files with same names. How to handle this in python? I need to rename those with "image_name_0001", "image_name_0002" like this.

Comment: your question is what function use to rename or how to generate proper names?

Answer (score 2):

You can maintain a `dict` with count of a names that have been seen so far and then use `os.rename()` to rename the file to this new name.

for example:

```
dic = {}
list_of_files = ["a","a","b","c","b","d","a"]
for f in list_of_files:
    if f in dic:
        dic[f] += 1
        new_name = "{0}_{1:03d}".format(f,dic[f])
        print new_name
    else:
        dic[f] = 0
        print f
```

**Output:**

```
a
a_001
b
c
b_001
d
a_002
```

Comment: This helps when i do it once. But since i need to do it many a times, dic = {} will make it zero each time. So any alternative?

Comment: @Sudhi1509 what do you mean my "do it many times"?  `dic ={}` should be at the top(before the loop).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the root filename i.e name = 'image_name', the extension, extension = '.jpg' and the path to the output folder, path, you can do:

```
*for each file*:
    moved = 0
    num = 0
    if os.path.exists(path + name + ext):
        while moved == 0:
            num++
            modifier = '_00'+str(num)
            if not os.path.exists(path + name + modifier + extension):
                *MOVE FILE HERE using (path + name + modifier + extension)*
                moved = 1
    else:
        *MOVE FILE HERE using (path + name + ext)*
```

There are obviously a couple of bits of pseudocode in there but you should get the gist